# bootstrap sidebar fixed with content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i use affix bootstrap  but don't work

i like set nav fix right  and create content div with 12 grid.(create fixed sidebar)

code :

```
<section class="container-fluid">
<div class="affix navbar-side">
    nav
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    content
</div>
<section>
```

css :

```
.navbar-side{
    width: 400px;
}
```

when content full overflow data go to under nav sider i don't like.

How fixed this problem ?

https://jsfiddle.net/8f8c8wur/

Comment: Create a fiddle or codepen and replicate the problem you are having.

Comment: oh sorry. adds fiddle ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I read in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_affix&stacked=h), the affix is style that you must create by your own and put it in the data-spy, not in class..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
```

Hope this help you..